# How to calculate date time different in Laravel Eloquent based on dynamic column minutes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to query based on two databases and columns.

```
$model->where('response_time', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(\DB::raw('anotherTable.created_at'))->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()))
```

`response_time` contains an integer of minutes, ie: 15

If the `anotherTable.created_at` - `response_time` (ie, sub 15 mins) is less than the current time, return the row.

I've tried the above but I'm having no luck and no idea how to debug my query. Any help appreciated.

Example query that should pass and return its row (1 minute over):

`response_time` 15

`anotherTable.created_at` 21-03-2022 13:40:00

Current time: `21-03-2022 13:56:00`

Comment: You can't use a column in Carbon to be used in a query. You'll have better luck using `DB::raw` with [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: Thanks @aynber something like `$model->raw('DATE_SUB(anotherTable.created_at, response_time) <= NOW()')` ? - Doesn't seem to be working either but looks right

Comment: youll have to either perform query in 2 stages or utilize sub queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why Carbon is not working

`Carbon` is unable to retrieve the value from the database during query generation on the PHP side (`$model->where()`). `Carbon` will instead execute immediately on the `string` value of `'anotherTable.created_at'` prior to issuing the query to the database. The equivalent of:

```
$offset = Carbon::now()
    ->subMinutes('anotherTable.created_at')
    ->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()); // 0 

$model->where('response_time', '<=', $offset); // WHERE responst_time <= 0
```

**Carbon Process Breakdown**

`Carbon\Traits\Date::__call()` is used to parse the action and units from the method name as `sub` and `minutes`.
The process conditionally calls `Carbon\Traits\Units::subUnit('minute', 'anotherTable.created_at')` [[sic]](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.57.0/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L2619) which calls `Carbon\Traits\Units::addUnit($unit, -$value, $overflow)` [[sic]](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.57.0/src/Carbon/Traits/Units.php#L333).

The `-$value` is ultimately processed by PHP as `-'anotherTable.created_at'` resulting in `0` as if you called `Carbon::now()->subMinutes(0)`.

The issue would have been pointed out if `Carbon` would throw a `TypeError` exception when provided a `string` for the `$value` argument, as opposed to the expected `int`. However, the `$value` argument of `Carbon\Traits\Units::subUnit($unit, $value)` is not type-hinted.

---

### MySQL Resolution

Instead of using `Carbon`, use the MySQL [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function to produce the difference in minutes between `anotherTable.created_at` and `NOW()` in the query.

**[db<>fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a215593cf6461b4079111f56a3d576a)**

Provided `anotherTable` is being added with a `JOIN` in the query.

```
$model->where(
    'response_time', '<=',  DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, anotherTable.created_at, NOW())')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try :)

```
$model->where('response_time', '<=', Carbon::now()
    ->diffInMinutes(\DB::raw('anotherTable.created_at')));
```

Comment: Since Carbon only resides in PHP, it would not have access to the value of `anotherTable.created_at` from the database at the time the query is being created. Carbon would instead execute and return a value before the query is sent to the database.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot rely on the table values being used in a carbon function.

Instead, you have to do your caulcations on the database.

The code below should work in theory, though I have not tested it out.

All culcations that require database data, are done on the database.

Carbon is only used to pass the condition value up to it.

```php
$model->where(
    DB::raw('DATE_SUB(anotherTable.created_at, INTERVAL response_time MINUTE)'), '<=', Carbon::now()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

i hope this will help you

```
Carbon::parse('21-03-2022 13:40:00')->diffInMinutes(new DateTime)
```

Or

```
Carbon::parse('21-03-2022 13:40:00')->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now())
```

in your case use this:

```
Carbon::parse(DB::raw('anotherTable.created_at'))->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now())
```

Comment: Since Carbon only resides in PHP, it would not have access to the value of `anotherTable.created_at` from the database at the time the query is being created. Carbon would instead execute and return a value before the query is sent to the database.