# Laravel: use value of another column within a function in Where statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datetime, eloquent

I have a Round model for a game in Laravel PHP. Each round has a start time (DATETIME) and a duration (INT) in minutes:

```
id | game_id  | duration | start_time
1  | 3        | 40       | 2022-06-22 19:29:26
2  | 3        | 20       | 2022-06-24 00:02:55
3  | 1        | 10       | 2022-06-25 10:56:05
```

a game will have multiple rounds, a round has ended if `start_time + duration > Carbon::now()`

Now what I can't seem to figure out is how to retrieve all rounds from a game that are still ongoing

I thought something like this but obviously this doesn't work because I can't put the "duration" column in the subMinutes function

```
return $game->whereHas('rounds', function ($query) {
            $query->where('start_time', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(duration));
        })->first();
```

Comment: Do you get an error? have you put it in single quotes to signalizes that it is also a column?

Comment: If I put it in single quotes then it recognises as simply a string and not the column value. error: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Units.php on line 327

Comment: eloquent can't process column values at run time see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728333/5193536

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this in SQL:

```
WHERE start_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL duration SECOND
```

or the same, in Eloquent:

```
$query->whereRaw(sql: 'WHERE start_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL duration SECOND');
```